# Nginx - Conflict with proxy_pass and redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxypass

I have this URL: `https://local.myweb.com/es-es`

I need change the URL to this one `https://local.myweb.com/es/es` externally, the "original" URL can't change.

I have use `proxy_pass` and it works correctly:

```
location /es/es {
    proxy_pass https://local.myweb.com/es-es;
}
```

But the original URL (the URL ended with `es-es`) is also accesible, but i need to redirect it to `es/es`.

If I add a redirect I get the error *To Many Redirects*.

```
rewrite ^/es-es(.*)$ https://$server_name/es/es permanent;
```

Is there any way to redirect `es-es`to `es/es` and that the `es-es` still works "under the woods".

Many thanks for the help!

### Updated

I add the entire nginx file

```
upstream fastcgi_backend_myweb {
   server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name local.myweb.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /Users/trublux/Sites/myweb;

    ssl_certificate     /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.myweb.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.myweb.key;

    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    server_name local.myweb.com;

    sendfile off;
    error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/myweb.error.log info;
    access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/myweb.access.log;


    location /es/es {
      proxy_pass https://local.myweb.com/es-es;
    }


    location / {
        absolute_redirect off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        # For D7 and above:
        # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    # Handle image styles for Drupal 7+
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend_myweb;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        # fastcgi_read_timeout should match max_execution_time in php.ini
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10m;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        #fastcgi_param HTTPS $fcgi_https;
    }

    # Expire rules for static content

    # Prevent clients from accessing hidden files (starting with a dot)
    # This is particularly important if you store .htpasswd files in the site hierarchy
    # Access to `/.well-known/` is allowed.
    # https://www.mnot.net/blog/2010/04/07/well-known
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known\/) {
        deny all;
    }

    # Prevent clients from accessing to backup/config/source files
    location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|conf|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    ## Regular private file serving (i.e. handled by Drupal).
    location ^~ /system/files/ {
        ## For not signaling a 404 in the error log whenever the
        ## system/files directory is accessed add the line below.
        ## Note that the 404 is the intended behavior.
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # js and css always loaded
    location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires -1;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you `proxy_pass`ing to itself?

Comment: Yes.
Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: We would need to see the entire `server` block to understand how the `es-es` URI is processed and then implement that within the location for `es/es` maybe.

Comment: @RichardSmith I have added the entire nginx file.
Thanks for you help.